# FPDF Header Footer Codeigniter 4 Not Showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I'm trying to add header and footer to my pdf file using fpdf
My controller code is:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Libraries\FPDF;

class Test extends BaseController
{
    function Header()
    {
        $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(30,10,'Test',1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->pdf = new fpdf();
        $this->pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $this->pdf->AddPage();
        $this->pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
            $this->pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
        $this->response->setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        $this->pdf->Output();
    }   
}
```

The pdf output is line numbers only without header footer. Any clue?

Comment: Putting `Header()` and `Footer()` in the controller has no effect. You must extend the FPDF class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's working by changing the code slightly following FPDF tuto2.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\FPDF;

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header()
    {
        $this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(20);
    }

    function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Printing line number '.$i,0,1);
$pdf->Output();
```

Thanks to Olivier PLATHEY for your great and simple FPDF class